# boost::bind can't work with conditional expression?

Tags: c++, boost

When I uncomment the conditional expression, the program will fail to compile under visual c++ 2008.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
typedef boost::function<void(int, int)> vii_t;
typedef boost::function<void(int)> vi_t;

void foo(int a, int b){}
void bar(int a){}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //vi_t test= true ? boost::bind(foo, _1, 100) : boost::bind(bar, _1);
    vi_t test1 = boost::bind(foo, _1, 100);
    vi_t test2 = boost::bind(bar, _1);
    //test(1);
    test1(1);
    test2(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a point of etiquette, please could you avoid compiler-specific constructs such as `_tmain` and `_TCHAR`.  Please use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: Could you please post the compiler error?

Comment: By the way, the standard headers (as `iostream`) are included with angular brackets, not with quotes (i.e.: `#include <iostream>`, not `"iostream"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `c ? x : y` x and y must be of the same type, or one must be convertible to the other. That common type is the type of the whole expression.

Presumably, `boost::bind` with different number of parameters return different types that are not convertible to each other. That they both might be convertible to `vi_t` doesn't help.

Comment: I agree -- as a test, if you cast the two rightmost expressions of the ternary operator to vi_t, it should compile.

Comment: Sounds right. Another way that should work is to replace the ternary operator with an if.

Comment: This is a consequence of a larger rule in C/C++ -- the type you expect to get never determines how that value is computed. So in code like 'float f=2/3;' or 'float f=foo(2);', the type of division used or the overload of 'foo' chosen will not in any way be affected by the fact that you store the result in a float.